# KBMMW ORM MetaExists(mwmdtTable) not supported

Tags: sql-server, delphi, orm, unidac

I am trying to create table in *MSSQL* using *kbmMWORM* with *uniDAC* connection.

Below is my *KbmmWTable* definition:

```
[kbmMW_Table('name:DEPT')]
TDept = class
private
  FCoGroup:string;
  FDeptCode:string;
  FDeptDesc:string;
public
  [kbmMW_Field('name:CoGroup, primary:true', ftFixedChar, 6)]
  [kbmMW_NotNull]
  property CoGroup:string read FCoGroup write FCoGroup;

  [kbmMW_Field('name:DeptCode, primary:true', ftFixedChar, 8)]
  [kbmMW_NotNull]
  property DeptCode:string read FDeptCode write FDeptCode;

  [kbmMW_Field('name:DeptDesc', ftWideString, 30)]
  [kbmMW_NotNull]
  property DeptDesc:string read FDeptDesc write FDeptDesc;
end;
```

Calling `ORM.CreateOrUpgradeTable(TDept)` resulting this error:

> exception class EkbMWexception with message 'MetaExists(mwmdtTable)
>   not supported'.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set the MetaData property of the UNIDAC Connection pool to one supporting MSSQL

Comment: kbmMWMSSQLMetaData is set to uniDac Connection pool. 
I tested using Single field primary key and the table is created/updated successfully.
Could it due to multi-field primary key and ORM cant handle it.?